# Which built-in .NET cryptography algorithm is the most secure?

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography

Which cryptography algorithm is the most secure that ships with .net?

Answer (score 20):

You cannot directly compare all types of cryptographic algorithms. That would be like comparing a sorting algorithm with a multiplication algorithm: they have different purposes.
That being said, I would answer:

- Symmetric cipher: [AES-256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)
- Asymmetric cipher: [RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) with 4096 bit key (I believe that is the maximum in .NET) or [ECDSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.aspx) with 571 bit key (but that is only supported in .NET 3.5)
- Hash: [SHA-512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx)
- Message Authentication Code: [HMAC with SHA-512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512.aspx)

That being said, those are overkill for most applications, and you should do fine using AES-128, RSA with 2048 bit key, SHA-256 and HMAC with SHA-256.

Comment: Rasmus, what would be ideal for a licence key?

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258994/net-cryptography-for-licence-keys#259458

Comment: FYI - I made a reference to this answer on the new Security SE site: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/what-are-the-realistic-and-most-secure-crypto-for-symmetric-asymmetric-hash-m

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat partial to [SHA-512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx). If 512 is a little excessive, the other members of the SHA-2 family might be helpful - [SHA-256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) and [SHA-384](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha384.aspx) are both in the SHA-2 family. But AviewAnew's suggestion of [AES 256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) is good as well.

Comment: the msdn examples don't seem to be using a key to generate the hash?

Comment: Because you don't use a key to generate the hash. A SHA hash will always be the same for a given input.

Comment: Since the tag is encryption, I think we wanted an encryption algorithm, rather than a Hash function.  ASDF - A Hash function is unkeyed.  A MAC (sometimes called a keyed hash function) uses a key and has a different purpose from SHA or AES.

Comment: That could be. Based on the question, though, SHA does fit the bill as a cryptographic hash function.